# Need to set a var into a link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this loop where I'm creating a link, but bootstrap modals prevents me to use PHP variables properly from the top loop (Yes a loop in loop). So I decided to use jQuery and get the id from the button when it's clicked, and that is fine, but how do I append this into the link without appending the whole link, because there is another ID variable which I'm using again in this links? Here in `$value->getId()` I need to append value from jQuery.

```
foreach ($exploredArtistBands as $band) {
    echo '<a href="/notification/invite/' . $value->getId() . '/' . $band['band_id'] . '">Join to ' . $band['name'] . '</a><br />';
}
```

```js
$('.invite').click(function(){
    $(this).attr('button-id')
});
```

Comment: What (relevant/[MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) HTML does that php generate?

Comment: Can you run the foreach loop inside the `.click` callback, that way you have the value of the `button-id` wen you need it

Comment: http://pastebin.com/hsgKnJkS

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the url for your link in the click event. You just have to turn your url into something that's easy to parse. Something like the following;

```
foreach ($exploredArtistBands as $band) {
    echo '<a href="/notification/invite/{id}/' . $band['band_id'] . '">Join to ' . $band['name'] . '</a><br />';
}
```

So you end up with a link like:

```
href="/notification/invite/{id}/band_id"
```

Now in your click handler, replace `{id}` with the id from the button.

```
$('.invite').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('button-id');
    var url = $(this).attr("href");
    $(this).attr("href", url.replace('{id}', id));
});
```

The click event will continue to bubble, but with a new url. This will ultimately direct your browser to the right place. This approach smells to me, but it works.

Comment: I think it's a rather nifty solution. jQuery will bind the correct element, so if there's other HTML inside the link, you don't have to worry about the right element. Simple and does the job!

Comment: Yes, but when i have more then 1  $('.invite') elements with different ids on each one Jquery replace everywhere the first clicked button, so still need something to be done ...